# Xively C library with ubuntu eclipse(gcc/g++) 32bit crosscompilation app connectivity

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, xively, beagleboneblack

I have optimised my ubuntu 13.04 running 64-bit machine to cross-compile for 32bit ARM and checked by developing c/c++ code the code is successfully running on 32bit ARM(BBBlack) NOW what I want to achieve is connectivity with the Xively server's updating and retrieving feeds/datapoints from datastreams.

*So I'm thinking to utilise the c library from Xively to use in my Ubuntu eclipse development environment* **will it work?**

**Will there be any crosscompilation problem's?** or **Is it all fine?**

**The following is what I'm getting when I run >> make -C src CC=arm-linux-eabi-gcc AR=arm-linux-eabi-gcc examples**

```
make: *** src: No such file or directory.  Stop.
nishant@Nishant-K53SC:~$ cd libxively
nishant@Nishant-K53SC:~/libxively$ make -C src CC=arm-linux-eabi-gcc AR=arm-linux-eabi-gcc libxively
make: Entering directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src'
make -C libxively
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/libxively'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/libxively'
make: Leaving directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src'
nishant@Nishant-K53SC:~/libxively$ make -C src CC=arm-linux-eabi-gcc AR=arm-linux-eabi-gcc libxively
make: Entering directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src'
make -C libxively
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/libxively'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/libxively'
make: Leaving directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src'
nishant@Nishant-K53SC:~/libxively$ make -C src CC=arm-linux-eabi-gcc AR=arm-linux-eabi-gcc examples
make: Entering directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src'
make -C examples
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples'
for dir in datapoint_delete datapoint_delete_range datastream_create datastream_delete datastream_get datastream_update feed_get feed_update; do (make -C $dir) || exit 1; done
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/datapoint_delete'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/datapoint_delete'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/datapoint_delete_range'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/datapoint_delete_range'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/datastream_create'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/datastream_create'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/datastream_delete'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/datastream_delete'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/datastream_get'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/datastream_get'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/datastream_update'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/datastream_update'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/feed_get'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/feed_get'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/feed_update'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples/feed_update'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src/examples'
make: Leaving directory `/home/nishant/libxively/src'
```

**UPDATES ERRORS WHILE BUILDING WITH LIBRARy:**

Build of configuration Debug for project Test **

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/Test.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3 -I/home/nishant/libxively/src/libxively -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/bits -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/ext -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/arm-linux-gnueabi -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/backward -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/decimal -includexively.h -includexi_helpers.h -includexi_err.h -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Test.d" -MT"src/Test.d" -o "src/Test.o" "../src/Test.cpp"
/home/nishant/workspace/Test/src/libxively.a: could not read symbols: File format not recognized
Finished building: ../src/Test.cpp

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Building target: Test
make: *** [Test] Error 1
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -L/home/nishant/workspace/Test/src -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib -o "Test"  ./src/Test.o   -lxively

**** Build Finished ****
```

Answer (score 1):

Xively C library should work on any 32-bit and 64-bit POSIX OS as well as various RTOS with lwIP.

To cross compile the library using `arm-linux-eabi-gcc`, you need to run the following command in the toplevel directory:

```
make -C src CC=arm-linux-eabi-gcc AR=arm-linux-eabi-gcc libxively
make -C src CC=arm-linux-eabi-gcc AR=arm-linux-eabi-gcc examples
```

## Detailed instructions

Below I will describe how to compile a simple example C program and statically link it with Xively library. This should provide enough background information. Although, I cannot provide information on how to fix Eclipse IDE as I doubt it's possible.

1. Create a directory and clone the library:

   ```
   mkdir hello_xively
   cd hello_xively
   git clone --recursive https://github.com/xively/libxively
   ```
2. Add the **`test.c`** file now as shown:

   ```
   #include "xively.h"

   int main() {

     xi_context_t* ctx = xi_create_context( XI_HTTP, "DUMMY_API_KEY_STRING", 123 );
     xi_delete_context( ctx );
     return 0;
   };
   ```
3. Build the library itself *(please note that `CC` and `AR` values for your target may differ)*:

   ```
   export CC=arm-linux-eabi-gcc  # C compiler fron-end for the ARM Linux target
   export AR=arm-linux-eabi-ar   # This is needed for the build to work
   export XI=`pwd`/libxively.a   # To store the output in current direcory
   make -C libxively/src libxively
   ```
4. Compile **`test.c`** and link it with the static library:

   ```
   $CC test.c \
     -I./libxively/src/libxively \
     libxively.a -o xively_static_test
   ```

You now can try copying the **`xively_static_test`** executable to the target device's filesystem and execute it, which should produce no output as it's a test example. No you can extend the above example to provide functionality you desire!

Comment: so I just need to do this once and for all and this Xively C library is configured ? and add it to the linux in the coneventional way?

Comment: Well, if you don't make changes to the library, then you shouldn't need to rebuild it. Otherwise you would need to teach your IDE that this is part of clean build.

Comment: So normally you'd want to make your IDE link to a static library, which you will find under `libxively/src/obj/libxively.a`.

Comment: I mean what kind of library have .a extension in C?

Comment: I ran the both make -C src CC=arm-linux-eabi-gcc AR=arm-linux-eabi-gcc libxively
 and make -C src CC=arm-linux-eabi-gcc AR=arm-linux-eabi-gcc examples but it feels like its already done what these statements are suppose to do as I ran "make all" while being in the libxively directory   ,**I'HVE ADDED THE RETURN PROMPT ABOVE**

Comment: I added the static library within the src folder a simple drag and drop then provided its path on the GCC C++ linker and added the includes in the GCC C++ in under properties>c++ Build> settings

Comment: Ok all done BUT while building I get the UPDATED ABOVE ERRORS

Comment: There is no point of panicking, perhaps you should go back one step and try to understand how linking static libraries works. I would suggest you try building a simple executable by hand, see my updated answer.

Comment: The includes now work and I think my library linking is just as fine as it should be, I HAVE ALREADY TESTED the machine with a simple c executable and it works so all related to c/c++ addons etc works now I have added a datastream example that I want to make work

Comment: Dude, I just finished writing it. Refresh the page please.

Comment: If you are in doubt about the next step, please do not update this question and post an new one instead.

Comment: One very small question im getting  undefined reference to `xi_create_context'
and  undefined reference to `xi_delete_context'  I think its generating because of this XI_HTTP ,

Comment: Did you follow the command-line instructions or you are getting this error from the IDE?

Comment: the function in the xively.h which is being filled with parameters and called goes like this:                                          **typedef enum {
    /** `http://api.xively.com` */
    XI_HTTP, 
    /** `https://api.xively.com` */
    XI_HTTPS,
    /** `telnet api.xively.com 8081` */
    XI_TCP,
    /** `openssl s_client -host api.xively.com -port 8091 -tls1` */
    XI_TCPS,
    /** `ws://api.xively.com:8080` */
    XI_WS,
    /** `wss://api.xively.com:8090` */
    XI_WSS,
} xi_protocol_t;  **       several urls are commented out!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37351/discussion-between-naaz-and-errordeveloper)